# Serial port communication (APT protocol) with Thorlabs KDC101 controller not working

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, serial-communication

I am trying to communicate with my Thorlabs KDC101 controller via a serial port connection using Qt on Linux and the [Thorlabs APT communication protocol](https://www.thorlabs.com/Software/Motion%20Control/APT_Communications_Protocol.pdf). I can open the COM port and also write the required bytes to this port, but the controller is not responing in any shape or form (the controller is fully functioning though).

I am very new to Qt and have written the following lines of code to talk to the controller:

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QIODeviceBase>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QByteArray message;
    QByteArray response;

    message.resize(6);
    message[0] = 0x23;
    message[1] = 0x02;
    message[2] = 0x00;
    message[3] = 0x00;
    message[4] = 0x50;
    message[5] = 0x01;


    QList<QSerialPortInfo> SerialPortList = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
    foreach (QSerialPortInfo info, SerialPortList)
    {
        qDebug() << "port name:" << info.portName();
        qDebug() << "serial number:" << info.serialNumber();
    }

    QSerialPort port;
    port.setPort(SerialPortList[0]);
    port.open(QIODeviceBase::ReadWrite);

    if (!port.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error: Failed to set BAUD RATE of COM port" << port.portName() << "to 115200";
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!port.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error: Failed to set DATA BITS of COM port" << port.portName() << "to 8";
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!port.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error: Failed to set STOP BITS of COM port" << port.portName() << "to 1";
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!port.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error: Failed to set PARITY of COM port" << port.portName() << "none";
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!port.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::HardwareControl))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error: Failed to set FLOW CONTROL of COM port" << port.portName() << "RTS/CTS";
        exit(1);
    }

    qint64 bytesWritten = port.write(message);

    qDebug() << bytesWritten << "bytes written to serial port.";

    port.close();

    return 0;
}
```

The project file looks as follows:

```
QT -= gui
QT += serialport

CONFIG += c++17 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

# Default rules for demployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Executing this program returns the correct name of the COM port as well as the correct serial number of the controller and the confirmation that 6 bytes were written to the serial port. Other than that, nothing happens.

The "message" correspondes to the command that should make the LED panel of the controller flash to identify itself ([Thorlabs APT communication protocol](https://www.thorlabs.com/Software/Motion%20Control/APT_Communications_Protocol.pdf), page 47). This does not happen unfortunately. I have also tried a number of other messages, again without any response.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Would be much appreciated!

Comment: Since the device appears to use hardware flow control, you probably should set the RTS before sending any data. i.e. use `if (!port.setRequestToSend(true)) { error ... }`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this does not work, unfortunately. Setting flow control to hardware control takes care of RTS already. In the Qt documentation it says:
"Note: An attempt to control the RTS signal in the HardwareControl mode will fail with error code set to UnsupportedOperationError, because the signal is automatically controlled by the driver."

Comment: Other than that the only thing I could think of is playing around with the DTR pin - I know that some Arduino micros are wired with the reset pin attached to the DTR pin of the USB/serial chip, so that manipulating that pin will reset the microcontroller. Also, did you try the example code using the FTD2XX.dll in the manual you posted? Does that at least work?

Comment: Also, just looked at the example code in the manual, it uses `FT_ResetDevice` *after* configuring the baud rate, parity, and stop bits. I'm not 100% sure what `FT_ResetDevice` does (the docs don't exactly say), but I could easily imagine that it also resets all settings to their default. So maybe the example code is wrong and the device is actually using a different baud rate (or parity or stop bit count) than what they specify? (Don't know the default for the chip though.) I could be way of base here though and the function doesn't reset that... (Not tried it myself.)

Comment: After trying to make an analog of this code work with a simple Arduino and experiencing the same problem, I have come to the conclusion that the problem probably is not in the code. My guess now is that the commands do not actually reach the serial devices (Thorlabs controller or Arduino) at all (even if `QSerialPort.write()` does not throw any error).

Comment: I personally don't have much experience with QtSerialPort, but I have used [libserialport](http://sigrok.org/wiki/Libserialport) extensively and can really recommend that. Perhaps you could try using that instead of Qt's version? It doesn't come with code to integrate with Qt directly (you'd have to write your own glue code), but it has so far always worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have not set the channel identification byte (#3, starting with 1); if I am not mistaken, all thorlabs units have at least one 'channel', so you should definitely try doing that.

If that does not work, the unit might be a card-slot type, meaning that you would need to address 'general' commands to the 'motherboard' of the unit (address byte 0x11), and the motion commands to the 'bay 1' (0x21), and not the 'generic USB x50'